# Register class In Autofac similar to the .NET Core default

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, autofac

I am using Autofac as an IoC Container. I have implemented this previously using .NET Core's IoC Container with the following code:

```cs
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IConverter>(
    new SynchronizedConverter(new PdfTools()));
```

How can I accomplish this in Autofac?

Answer (score 3):

Read this: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html

You could do something like:

```
containerBuilder.RegisterInstance(new SynchronizedConverter(new PdfTools()))
    .As<IConverter>();
```